# C++ passing string references into functions

Tags: c++, string

I have two questions about C++ strings:

1. The expression `string func(string & s)` works in a similar fashion to `string & func(string & s)`, but how do you determine if the return value is referential or non-referential?
2. Why can't I use `func((string)str)` instead?

The code is as follows, including comments showing my intent with questions 1 and 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Q1:string func(string & s){
string & func(string & s){
    s[2]='S';
    return s;
}

int main(){
    char str[]={'H','H','H','H'};
    string name="HHHHH";
    //Q2:string tmp=(string)str;
    //string rest=func(tmp);
    string rest=func((string)str);
    cout<<"rest"<<rest;
}
```

Comment: As for Q1: it should be obvious if you know what C++ references are. As for Q2: you cannot construct an std::string from an array of chars unless that array of chars is null-terminated.

Comment: `char str[] = { 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H' }` is an array of four characters, not a C-string. C-strings are terminated with a nul-byte, equivalent to `char str[] = { 'H', 'H', 'H', H', 0 /* or '\0' */ };` or `char str[] = "HHHH";`

Answer (score 3):

Q1: Returning `string&` returns a reference to the original string. Returning `string` returns a copy of the original string. Also, returning `string&` makes the function call expression an lvalue, whereas returning `string` makes it an rvalue.

Q2: `(string)str` creates a temporary `std::string` initialized from `str`. Therefore it's an rvalue. But `func` expects its argument to be an lvalue, since the parameter is a non-`const` lvalue reference.

Comment: I got the point:its because of non-const rather than tmp-obj that make me wrong